# Emscripten: Module not found: Can't resolve 'env'

Tags: c++, webassembly, emscripten

I am trying to compile a small project which references a static library (`.a`) in `/usr/local/lib` and it's header (`.h`) files in `/usr/local/include/test` into a **standalone** wasm file. The following code runs fine with no compilation errors.

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "libtest/libtest.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    LibTest Test;
    std::cout << Test.version() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(test_project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(/usr/local/include)

link_directories(/usr/local/lib)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} test)
```

However, when I compile into `wasm` using the following command:

`emcc main.cpp -I/usr/local/include -Os -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -o main.wasm`

I get the error: `Module not found: Can't resolve 'env'` when importing the `wasm` file into the client application.

Here's how I'm importing it:

```
const Component = dynamic({
    loader: async () => {
        const module = await import("../../main.wasm");
    },
    ssr: false,
});
```

**NOTE:** This will work fine if remove the imported library and do just about anything else (e.g. the `Hello World` or `add(x, y)` function examples.)

Anyone ran into this problem?

I'm assuming that the `emcc` command I am running is failing to compile the library correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You are compiling it into pure Wasm but the C++ code contains functions without a Wasm equivalent; they have to be replaced with JavaScript equivalents and "imported" into the Wasm.

This is normally done by Emscripten but you are telling it not to do this when you specify that you want a **standalone** Wasm file.